# PHP files being run using shell_exec() accessing cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I am building a site that is intentionally vulnerable to LFI exploits for teaching purposes (similar to [Natas](http://overthewire.org/wargames/natas/)). Here is my code:

File being run through CLI (/etc/flags/challenge):

```
<?php
//This file must be located at /etc/flags/challenge
require_once('/var/www/html/class.sqlite.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/inc.func.php');
$dbuser = base64_decode($_COOKIE['loggedin']);
$sqlite = new sqlite("/var/www/html/db/$dbuser/challenge.db");
$flag = $sqlite->getflag($dbuser);
echo "The flag is $flag";
?>
```

Main file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Challenge</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.php?file=home">Home</a>  <a href="index.php?file=about">About</a>
<br>
<?php
if (array_key_exists('file', $_GET)) {
    $shell = shell_exec('php ' . $_GET['file']);
    echo $shell;
}
?>
<!--The flag is located at /etc/flags/challenge-->
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, `/etc/flags/challenge` is not able to access the `loggedin` cookie. What is the best way to allow the `/etc/flags/challenge` to access that cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the cookie in the main script and then pass it as a command-line argument:

In the main file:
Add `$cookie = $_COOKIE['loggedin'];`, and change `$shell = ...` to `$shell = shell_exec('php ' . $_GET['file'] . ' ' . $cookie);`

In the CLI file:
Add `$cookie = $argv[1];`

Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.php) for more info on command line arguments in PHP